# background sound for Mozilla

Tags: html, audio

i know `<bgsound>` html is not support for Mozilla, The HTML Background Sound Element `<bgsound>` is an Internet Explorer element associating a background sound with a page.

how to autoplay background sound & support for mozilla ?

Answer (score 0):

you can use object of javascript **Audio**
for example

```
var audio = new Audio("path to your sound file");
audio.play();
```

or check **html tag audio** http://www.w3schools.com/Tags/tag_audio.asp There is attribute autoplay

or you can use **SoundManager**:http://www.schillmania.com/projects/soundmanager2/